# Let $p$ be a prime number and let $Z=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\: z^{p^{n}}=1$ for some $n \in N\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $Z=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: z^{p^{n}}=1$ for some $n \in\Bbb N\}$.

(a) Show that every proper subgroup of $Z$ is of the form $H_{k}$ for some $k$, where $H_k=\{z\in C: z^{p^{k}}=1\}$.

Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $Z$. If $H\ne\{e\}$, then there exists $z_1 \in H$ such that $z_{1}^{p^{n_1}}=1 $ for some $n_1 \in N$.

Now since $H$ is a proper subgroup of $Z$, there exists a natural number $n^{*}$ such that a $H_{n} \not\subset H$ for all $n \ge n^{*}$. I now need to show that $H=H_{n^{*}-1}$.

Does it seem alright??

Comment: We need to use the fact that a $p^m$-th root of unity is **missing** from $H$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Now since $H$ is a proper subgroup of $Z$, there exists a natural no $n^{*}$ such that a $H_{n} \not\subset H$ for all $n \ge n^{*}$. I now need to show that $H=H_{n^{*}-1}$.

Does it seem alright??

Comment: Yes, that's the strategy.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can I not do this for any no?? Why do I need a power of $p$??

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $Z=\cup_k H_k$ and $H_k\subset H_{k+1}$, as $H\neq Z$ then there exits $k_1$ such that $H_{k_1}\not\subset H$, now consider $k=\min\{p \ / H_p\not\subset H \}$, and show that $H=H_{k-1}$.

Comment: What do I need $k$ for??